# C# timing functioning similar to Java System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way to obtain timing functionality which uses primitives only and does not generate objects.  This functionality will potentially be used hundreds of times per second therefore I'm looking for maximal performance. I would like  millisecond granularity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Environment.TickCount
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx

Comment: Wrong answer. TickCount: A 32-bit signed integer containing the amount of time in milliseconds that has passed since the last time the computer was started. System.currentTimeMillis() - the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. (Long value)

Answer (score 3):

[System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) is the most commonly used timing mechanism. It has fairly low overhead and can get millisecond granularity no problem. If you need more precision I would reccomend an external profiler.